# Can't debug Symfony with ContainerAware command function

Tags: php, symfony, docker, xdebug

I get the following error in Symfony 3.4 when I trying to extend the `BaseCommand` and run the code in Xdebug.

```
[docker://mysite:dev/]:php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9001 -dxdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1 /opt/project/website/src/App/Command/Affiliates/myCommand.php
Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\Console\BaseCommand' not found
```

I have included it like this

```
use AppBundle\Console\BaseCommand;
```

the class extends `BaseCommand` an abstract class

```
class myCommand extends BaseCommand { 
}

abstract class BaseCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {       
}
```

Comment: I think you sould debug "bin/console yourcommand", not opt/project/website/src/App/Command/Affiliates/myCommand.php

Comment: You are trying to execute/debug that PHP file **directly** which bypasses framework's bootstrap logic. You need to execute/debug actual command that you would run in command line instead (e.g. `bin/console myCommand` -- sorry, not Symfony user here so do not remember exact syntax). Basically -- script to debug is `bin/console` and the rest are parameters (I'm talking if PhpStorm is used; but other IDE/editor will have the same logic)

Comment: Yes @LazyOne, the exact name command can obtain by bin/console list

Comment: yes bin/console is correct and I am able to use this if I have used bash to enter my docker container.  However trying to debug inside PHPstorm, There are options in phpstorm under Edit Configuration > Run/Debug configurations but the only options seems to be Shell Script , not sure how to add correct options

Comment: @GAV **PHP Script** type. AFAIK your `bin/console` is a plain PHP script (when executing you do `php bin/console command_and_params_here`, right?)

Comment: @LazyOne yes that's correct